# How to make QLineEdit editing enabled while text comes from a QPushButton?

Tags: c++, qt

In my project, I am using two `QPushButton` and two `QLineEdit`. I am connecting these `QPushButton` with these `QLineEdit` in such a way, so that `QPushButton` allow the user to select a folder from hard drive and after selection, the corresponding `QLineEdit` will display the `URL` path of the selected folder.

I also like to allow the user to write the `URL` by himself own if he does not want to click `QPushButton` and choose folder. And also if the user wants, he can also edit the `URL` after selecting by `QPushButton`.

Here I am facing two problems.

1) One `QLineEdit` allows user to write but another one does not.

2) When user presses on `QPushButton`, writing mode on corresponding `QLineEdit` becomes disabled.

The following is the code. Here `InputLine` and `OutputLine` are two `QLineEdit`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

/* Setting the size of Mainwindow */
this->setWindowTitle("Crop Multiple Object");
this->setFixedHeight(600);
this->setFixedWidth(800);

/* Setting QLabel for displaying Image  */
QLabel* image= new QLabel(this);
image->setGeometry(20,130,500,430);
image->setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: rgb(200,200,200)}");
image->show();

/* Set input URL */
QPushButton* InputURL = new QPushButton(this);
InputURL->setText("Input URL");
InputURL->setGeometry(20,30,100,30);
connect(InputURL, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(ReceiveInputURL()));

/* Set output URL */
QPushButton* OutputURL = new QPushButton(this);
OutputURL->setText("Output URL");
OutputURL->setGeometry(20,80,100,30);
connect(OutputURL, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(ReceiveOutputURL()));

/* Set Input URL Line*/
InputLine->setGeometry(140,30,400,30);
OutputLine->setGeometry(140,80,400,30);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::ReceiveInputURL()
{
    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Input Image File"),
                                                 "/home",
                                                 QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                 | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    if(!dir.isEmpty())
    {
        InputLine->setText(dir + "/");
    }

}

void MainWindow::ReceiveOutputURL()
{
    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Output Image File"),
                                                 "/home",
                                                 QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                 | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    if(!dir.isEmpty())
    {
        OutputLine->setText(dir+ "/");
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you declared the QLineEdit?

Comment: In `MainWindow.h` as a private variable.
`private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QLineEdit* InputLine = new QLineEdit(this);
    QLineEdit* OutputLine = new QLineEdit(this);`

Comment: Please explain to me your 2 problems because I do not understand them

Comment: My 1st problem is, In one QLineEdit, I can write something, but in the another QLineEdit, I am not able to write.
2nd problem is, when I click once in QPushButton, the QLineEdit become disabled. I mean I can not write in the QLineEdit after clicking QPushButton.

Comment: I am implementing your code, to see if I also have the same problem.

Comment: could show an image of your GUI

Comment: Ok, I need 3 minutes to make picture.

Comment: It works for me correctly, I can edit the QLineEdit before and after choosing the folder.

Comment: This is my test code, download it and open it with QtCreator, and check if you have the same problem. https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/15e73b03a972afed6a05a8d1fc770522

Comment: Ok I am checking.

Comment: Yes, now it is working perfectly. But I am surprised as you didn't change anything.

Comment: You can share your code to check what the problem is. A new opinion always helps.

Comment: Here is my code https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C0s-T4ayCE-dAmYXY59suVES8eFmPCuq?usp=sharing

Comment: What I see is that you are creating the QLineEdit before creating the widget, so it seems that you are deleting the Qt access to the QLineEdit. I find it strange that you create the QLineEdit outside the constructor. Qt has a special constructor that registers the widgets in QApplication, and it seems to me that you have created it before and therefore are not registered as children of the main widget.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. It's really new for me.

Comment: Where did you get the idea of creating the instance in the .h?

Comment: I thought, I should make it private variable and only way to make it private is declaring them in .h. My wrong conception was this.

Comment: One thing is to declare the pointer as a private member, as it is in my code, and another thing is to create the instance. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc They are added to the list of children just fine. The issue is that the central widget is on top of the line edits he created, so it stops all the mouse events from passing through.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating your `QLineEdit` objects before the `centralWidget` of `MainWindow` is created. This puts the central widget on top of your `QLineEdit` widgets, so it blocks the mouse events from passing through. To test this, you can disable mouse events for central widget with `centralWidget()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);`, and you will notice that your `QLineEdit` widgets can be accessed by mouse clicks.

However, you shouldn't place any widgets directly on the `MainWindow`. This is not how `QMainWindow` is supposed to be used. Instead you should place your widgets on the `centralWidget`. You should read the [docs of `QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) to know more.